# In a triangle ABC, prove that a^3cos3B + 3a^2bcos(2B-A) +3ab^2cos(B-2A) + b^3cos3A= c^3, where a, b, c, A, B, C has their usual meanings

Tags: complex-numbers

In a triangle $ABC$, prove that $$a^3\cos 3B + 3a^2b\cos(2B-A) +3ab^2\cos(B-2A) + b^3\cos3A= c^3$$ where $a, b, c, A, B, C $ have their usual meanings. 
I found this question in a chapter of complex numbers, but I cannot imagine that how it will be done by any touch of complex number.

Comment: start with http://www.math-only-math.com/projection-formulae.html

Answer (score 1):

We have $c = a\cos B + b \cos A$ and $a\sin B - b\sin A = 0$. Thus we can write
$$c = a(\cos B + i \sin B) + b(\cos A - i\sin A) = a e^{iB} + be^{-iA}$$
Now cube both sides to get
$$c^3 = a^3 e^{3iB} + 3a^2b e^{2iB-iA} + 3ab^2e^{iB-2iA} + b^3e^{-3iA}$$
Equate the real parts to obtain the required. relation

Comment: many many thanks you man